# How to use JdbcClientDetailsService of spring security oauth2?

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I learn how to use oauth2 from the example `sparklr2`, but it use `inMemoryClientDetailsService`. which is not the case for production, an oauth2 webapp like twitter should let new client to register. so eventually will use `JdbcClientDetailsService`. but the example and documentation of `spring security oauth2` does not provide what is the correct way to do registration in code.

here is what I guess from looking at the project source.

```
JdbcClientDetailsServiceBuilder client = new JdbcClientDetailsServiceBuilder();
        client.dataSource(dataSource)
        .withClient("my-trusted-client-with-secret")
         .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
         .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
         .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
         .secret("somesecret");
client.build();
```

it writes a record to the database `oauth_client_details` table, but I want to know if I am doing it correctly (best practice)? does anyone know?